# Set space between two HTML table columns

Tags: html

I need to set some space between columns 2 and 3 :

```
<tbody>
<td><input type="text" size="20"</td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"</td>
<td style="width:50px"><input type="text" size="80"</td> <!-- I also tried: width="50"-->
<td><input type="text" size="4"</td>
```

I want columns two and three to be far apart. How can I do this ?

Comment: With `margin` and `padding` I suppose?

Comment: I tried this : `style="margin-right:50px"`

Comment: Try using CSS to style your table. And you can share an image of how you exactly want your table.

Comment: This may be affecting the layout; your example isn't closing the input tags. Just a heads up!

Comment: Thank you. margin does not work, but padding works: `style="padding-right: 50px"`

Comment: No problem, make sure to close your input tags though!

Comment: cell-padding or cell-spacing would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will work. Just add 's with widths.

```
<td style="width:100"></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"</td>
<td style="width:100"></td>
<td style="width:50px"><input type="text" size="80"</td>
```